# Change "display:none" to "display:block" with on hover doesn't work

Tags: css, hover, display

Ok so thats the problem here: 
I want a panel to be displayed when I hover over each nav li item. But it just don't work.

The html:

```
         <nav class="row">
                <ul class="nav header-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">item 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">item 2</a>
                    </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">item 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>  
            </nav>
            <div class="dropdown-parent">
                <div class="dropdown-panel row">

                </div>  
            </div>
```

And here's the css:

```
.header-nav{
    height: 80px;
    width:100%; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    li{
        background-color:$honey;   
        position: relative;  
        height:77px;  
        width:9.8%;
        margin:1px; 
        margin-top:0px;
        border-radius: 7px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 0px black;

        a{
            color:black;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    }
}

.dropdown-parent{
    text-align: center;
    display:none;
    .dropdown-panel{
        margin-top:2px;
        padding-top:50px;
        padding-bottom:50px;
        display:inline-block;
        width:95%;
        height: auto;
        background-color:white;
        z-index:1;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 0px black;
    }
}
```

So I made a simple css on hover animation to display .dropdown-parent:

```
.header-nav{
    li{
        &:hover{
            .dropdown-parent{
                display:block !important;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately It didn't work and I can't pinpoint the reason why.
I even tried to bypass the issue by using jquery but that doesn't seem to help either...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("header-nav li").hover(function(){
    $("dropdown-parent").css("display", "block");
});
```

});

So what's going on here?

Comment: The dupe link explains the selector issue (and have some script replacements), your own script has some typo's, missing the dot in `.class-selector`.

Comment: Simply put, CSS selectors can only target children and siblings with a shared parent.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in CSS, as CSS doesn't work this way- it's cascading style sheet, meaning you cannot control elements what are not children of your selector, and in your case `header-nav` and `dropdown-parent` are not even siblings. Your JS solution should work nicely, but you have wrong selectors there, it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".header-nav li").hover(function(){
    $(".dropdown-parent").css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was stuck for hours on this...

Comment: happenes to all of us sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS can not work, because `.dropdown-parent` is not a child of the list-item

The JS approach doesn't work because both the selectors are wrong (a dot `.` is missing, those are classnames and not elements)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".header-nav li").hover(function(){
    $(".dropdown-parent").css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hopefully with more experience I will avoid such mistakes!